# Symbol's function definition is void: edmacro-parse-keys

Tags: debugging, emacs

I am trying to switch between buffers in emacs. Normally this has always worked for years. But now I am getting an error saying:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: edmacro-parse-keys
```

I see there is a lot of different error on google about the: `Symbol's function definition is void`
But I can't find my specific problem.
Anyone has any idea?

Thanks

--------------Update-----------------------

Here is the debug error

```
    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function edmacro-parse-keys)
  (edmacro-parse-keys key)
  (define-key iswitchb-mode-map (edmacro-parse-keys key) fun)
  (let* ((key (car K)) (fun (cdr K))) (define-key iswitchb-mode-map (edmacro-parse-keys key) fun))
  (lambda (K) (let* ((key (car K)) (fun (cdr K))) (define-key iswitchb-mode-map (edmacro-parse-keys key) fun)))(("<right>" . iswitchb-next-match))
  mapc((lambda (K) (let* ((key (car K)) (fun (cdr K))) (define-key iswitchb-mode-map (edmacro-parse-keys key) fun))) (("<right>" . iswitchb-next-match) ("<left>" . iswitchb-prev-match) ("<up>" . ignore) ("<down>" . ignore)))
  iswitchb-local-keys()
  run-hooks(iswitchb-define-mode-map-hook)
  iswitchb-read-buffer("iswitch ")
  iswitchb()
  iswitchb-buffer()
  call-interactively(iswitchb-buffer nil nil)
  command-execute(iswitchb-buffer)
```

Comment: `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and then copy and paste the backtrace into your question after triggering the error.

Comment: `(require 'edmacro)` should cure the symptom, although it's not quite clear what the disease is. Version information might help narrow down the problem.

Comment: `edmacro-parse-keys` is defined in `edmacro.el`, which gets autoloaded when you use something like `kbd` (which calls `read-kbd-macro`, which is autoloaded from `edmacro.el`). So it looks like you either need to `(require 'edmacro)` explicitly or use something like `kbd` so that it gets loaded automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described on [emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IswitchBuffers#toc4) - you need to add

```
(require 'edmacro)
```

to your config file

Comment: Thanks, this did it. I just don't understand why this suddenly was required, when it has worked for several years. I did not change in my .emacs file, nor did I update emacs or anything. But thanks again